# Android XML internal storage

Tags: java, android, xml, single-responsibility-principle, open-closed-principle

I am trying to save some data using XML in android to save into the devices internal storage.

I want to be sure the app is written by the **open/closed** and **single responsibility** -principle.
(So i could easly switch between methods of storage)

```
-domain
|---db
|---|---appReader
|---|---|---AppReader.java
|---|---|---XMLAppReader.java
|---|---appWriter
|---|---|---AppWriter.java
|---|---|---XMLAppWriter.java   
|---DBFacade.java
|---DBFacadeImpl.java
-MainActivity.java
```

This is my current structure,...

The problem i am facing now, is that in every tutorial about android and xml they use the function `openFileOutput(filename,Context.Mode_Append)` I guess this is a function from Activity superclass ?

How would i have to initialise my `FileOutputStream` and still keep my **open/closed** and **single responsibility**  principle intact ?

Should i pass an Activity instance to my XMLAppWriter constructor ?
Doesn't this undermine the **Single responsibility**  principle ?

Comment: "The problem i am facing now, is that in every tutorial about android and xml they use the function openFileOutput(filename,Context.Mode_Append)" -- certainly not every one. "I guess this is a function from Activity superclass ?" -- `openFileOutput()` is a method on `Context`, and `Activity` inherits from `Context`. `getFilesDir()` is another method on `Context`, one which returns a `File` object pointing to where you can read and write files for your app's main portion of internal storage.

Comment: So you are saying i could add a Context param to my XMLWriter constructor ?

Comment: I have no idea. Out of ~7 billion people on the planet, you are the only one who knows what your `XMLWriter` is, what is using it, what API it exposes to those that are using it, etc.

Comment: Ugh, the name is quite self-explanatory. It uses XML to save data (write to storage). my question clearly states the problem. I need to use the function 'openFileOutput(..)' which is a method on 'Context'. My XMLWriter is a single existing class which only implements AppWriter nor does it extend any other class. So does adding a Context param not undermine the SRP ?

Comment: "the name is quite self-explanatory" -- yes, but the name does not document the implementation or its usage. "I need to use the function 'openFileOutput(..)' which is a method on 'Context'" -- no, you need `XMLWriter` to be able to write XML. That does not necessarily imply the use of `openFileOutput()`, nor does it imply that `XMLWriter` has to be the one to call `openFileOutput()` or `getFilesDir()`. "So does adding a Context param not undermine the SRP?" -- IMHO, no more than would a `File`, or a `String`, or a `boolean` parameter.

Comment: "That does not necessarily imply the use of openFileOutput(), nor does it imply that XMLWriter has to be the one to call openFileOutput() " Didn't I state that I need the use of this function in my main post ?

Comment: "Didn't I state that I need the use of this function in my main post ?" -- yes, and your statement is incorrect. Since you claim that "the name is quite self-explanatory", then `XMLWriter` needs to write XML. There are many ways of doing that in Android. Only one involves `openFileOutput()`. You may *want* to use that method; you do not "need" to use that method.

Comment: then please direct me to a tutorial without its usage ...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage

Comment: This does not make use of XML,"then XMLWriter needs to write XML. There are many ways of doing that in Android" please provide me with one of these other ways to write XML files on android. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: hahahahaha, sorry this makes me laugh. You just keep on getting off topic more and more. I am not interested in another way of saving to file. I WANT XML. please read the question more clearly. Thanks. lmao. PS. Stop commenting, you're only making it worse....

Comment: "I am not interested in another way of saving to file" -- I responded to your "please direct me to a tutorial without its usage" request, where you clearly were interested in another way of "saving to file".

Comment: Nop, I was interessted on how to save XML file without the usage of `openFileOutput()`. "then XMLWriter needs to write XML. There are many ways of doing that in Android. Only one involves openFileOutput(). " please read clearly what you have written before you post it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pass activity instance as parameter, you can use application's context method, which doesn't violate single responsibility principle.

```
getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(name, mode);
```

Comment: This doesn't help me at all, To make use of 'getApplicationContext()' I need to call it from within a class that extends the Activity class.

Comment: You can extends android Application class, public YourApp extends Application { //... }, and to initialize in YourApp with getApplicationContext(). But you need to specify the application name in your manifest file also.

Comment: So in my constructor of the `XMLAppWriter` (the class where i need to use the `openFileOutput(...)` method) I need to call `getApplicationContext` ?

Comment: Yes, pass the result of getApplicationContext() as a parameter of XMLAppWriter constructor. XMLAppWriter(Context context), then context.openFileOutput(...)